# FaceTime dims all other audio during video calls – how to stop that happening?

Tags: audio, macos, facetime, defaults, sound-volume

Is there a hidden preference or something I can get at through `defaults write`?

I'm running El Capitan 10.11.2 Beta (15C31f)